# Sorting with SortedSet to remove duplicate value dosen't change

Tags: android

I have a List of Object am I want to remove the duplicate object(With object property) to be removed. The below code works fine first time. But when I again try to remove duplicate the values by executing the same code, the previous sorted values comes. Please rectify me the errors in the code.

Note : the List mCaseloadsHeads is defined publicly in my class

```
  //Getting the values from the web service
    mCaseloadsHeads = parsedXML.getCaseLoadValues("get_Caseload_ClientServiceGroupID", param);
        Iterator<Caseload> iterator = mCaseloadsHeads.iterator();
                            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                                removeDuplicateClientName.add(iterator.next());
                            }
                            mCaseloadsHeads.clear();
                            mCaseloadsHeads.addAll(removeDuplicateClientName);

            SortedSet<Caseload> removeDuplicateClientName = new TreeSet<Caseload>(
                        new Comparator<Caseload>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Caseload caseload0, Caseload caseload1) {
                                return caseload0.ClientName.compareTo(caseload1.ClientName);

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Any one to solve this issue ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set, can't hold duplicates per definition

For me there are this possible problems

1. Your .clear(); fails, are you sore mCaseloadsHeads.isEmpty(); is true?
2. Your Comparator Fails

if ClientName is a String (refering to your other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19240845/sorting-values-with-comparator-changes-all-the-values-with-that-object) it is, something like this (return 0 means they are equal)

```
   SortedSet<Caseload> removeDuplicateClientName = new TreeSet<Caseload>(
                    new Comparator<Caseload>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Caseload caseload0, Caseload caseload1) {
                            return caseload0.ClientName.equals(caseload1.ClientName) ? 0 : 1;
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Hey existing code works fine, But the only problem is to refresh the sorted set. Any way to refresh it ??

Comment: Im not sure i know your problem, butwhats about -> removeDuplicateClientName.clear() after addAll? or just initialise it new when you use it?